What is it about nicotine products that restrict their sale to children?
In the UK children are not allowed to buy cigarettes and many other nicotine products.  This Nursing Times article describes the legality of selling non-tobacco nicotine pouches to children as a "loophole".
What exactly is restricted when it comes to selling nicotine products to children?

Maybe the legal restrictions are on tobacco and not on nicotine?

I suspect that may be part of it, but tobacco free nicotine vapes are restricted.
